# html Input box in android mobile browser opens and quickly closed keypad on touch

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

So on iOS mobile browser, it's fine. For my android chrome and samsung internet both do this.

I have an iframe that opens and in the iframe I have an input box, type text or tel. When I press on it to put the cursor there, the keypad comes up and then closes in 1/2 second. I removed all my js and css and just did a plain input box same thing.

Also of note, seems to be ok, on desktop view.

This is in my header, but other than that I removed everything

Comment: Maybe the iframe page is doing some kind of loading activity. Try doing like `frames[0].onload = function(){ /* run your code in here */});` You don't have to use that way to get the iframe and it would have to be the first one on the page for that to work. Of course, you should know to access the iframe window with `frames[0].contentWindow`. But you would have to have CORS access for that. Keep in mind dynamic code could have to happen before your code is run as well as any asynchronous activity.

Comment: It works fine on iphone and desktop chrome mobile simulator. I can paste to the input box if I hold my finger there.

Comment: `IframeWindow.Element.focus()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because I had some javascript in it that would close the iframe when it is in landscape mode. This is probably a bug because I never put it in landscape mode, somehow the keyboard triggers this.

Now for some devices, for some reason when the keyboard is opened it thinks it's in landscape mode (I'm on a note 9, so very common device).

This is the code that's killing it, I'll fix this

```
if (isMobile) {
    function orientationPortraitListener(mql) {
        if (mobileModalIframe) {
            if (mql.matches) {
                mobileModalIframe.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                mobileModalIframe.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }

    //orientationMediaQueryList = matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)"); //This will fail
    orientationMediaQueryList = matchMedia("screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 13/9)"); //this is the fix
    orientationPortraitListener(orientationMediaQueryList);
    orientationMediaQueryList.addListener(orientationPortraitListener);
}
```